# Uncaught ReferenceError: Nh63f2zxDC9C_6m25Fc is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMPEP.png)

Js seems to swear at push . I checked to change id = 1 and everything worked. Is there any way to get around this error? it finds an error and stops executing the code

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfmTY.png)

I use push to auto-generate id but this seems to create problems

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE41s.png)

I'm trying to add a product to the cart by id, but it doesn't understand the generated id, I tried changing id = 1 and it worked, but unfortunately I think that this will not be the best solution. I still want to use the auto-generated id by push, but how can I fix this?

app.js

```
 firebase.initializeApp(config2);
 
let openShopping = document.querySelector('.shopping');
let closeShopping = document.querySelector('.closeShopping');
let list = document.querySelector('.list');
let listCard = document.querySelector('.listCard');
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let total = document.querySelector('.total');
let quantity = document.querySelector('.quantity');

openShopping.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    body.classList.add('active');
})
closeShopping.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    body.classList.remove('active');
})


let products = null;
let listCards  = [];
function initApp(){
    firebase.database().ref('Products/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var data=snapshot.val();
        products = data;

        for(let[key,value] of Object.entries(products)){
            let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.classList.add('item');
        newDiv.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${value.image}">
            <div class="title">${value.pname}</div>
            <div class="price">${value.price.toLocaleString()}</div>
            <button onclick="addToCard(${key})">Add To Card</button>`;
        list.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
});
}
initApp();
function addToCard(key){
    if(listCards[key] == null){
        // copy product form list to list card
        listCards[key] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products[key]));
        listCards[key].quantity = 1;
    }
    reloadCard();
}
function reloadCard(){
    listCard.innerHTML = '';
    let count = 0;
    let totalPrice = 0;
    listCards.forEach((value, key)=>{
        totalPrice = totalPrice + value.price;
        count = count + value.quantity;
        if(value != null){
            let newDiv = document.createElement('li');
            newDiv.innerHTML = `
                <div><img src="${value.image}"/></div>
                <div>${value.pname}</div>
                <div>${value.price.toLocaleString()}</div>
                <div>
                    <button onclick="changeQuantity(${key}, ${value.quantity - 1})">-</button>
                    <div class="count">${value.quantity}</div>
                    <button onclick="changeQuantity(${key}, ${value.quantity + 1})">+</button>
                </div>`;
                listCard.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
    })
    total.innerText = totalPrice.toLocaleString();
    quantity.innerText = count;
}
function changeQuantity(key, quantity){
    if(quantity == 0){
        delete listCards[key];
    }else{
        listCards[key].quantity = quantity;
        listCards[key].price = quantity * products[key].price;
    }
    reloadCard();
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="">
    
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1>
            <div class="shopping">
                <img src="image/shopping.svg">
                <span class="quantity">0</span>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="list">
          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h1>Card</h1>
        <ul class="listCard">
        </ul>
        <div class="checkOut">
            <div class="total">0</div>
            <div class="closeShopping">Close</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/7.14.1-0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```